# Dynamic DNS and reverse proxies: Can this be done?

Tags: apache, dns, tomcat7, reverse-proxy

Here is my situation. I have a LAN at home, behind a regular router.

I have my server on 192.168.0.9, on this I have bind9 running, apache2 on port 80. Tomcat on port 8082 and another tomcat on port 8083.

I have successfully setup bind so that when I am inside my LAN I can enter:

app1.mylan.com  Apache will reverse proxy this to app1.mylan.com:8082 and it shows in the browser as app1.mylan.com

Same goes for app2. (i.e. app2.mylan.com -> app2.mylan.com)

However, my router has dynamic dns setup.

How can I reach app1.mylan.com via dynamic dns. I've tried setting up a URL redirect with my DNS provider (even enabling cloaking)

but what happens is that in the browser, the apache server tries to serve up the content as if it was on port 80, and I get a 404.

It's as if the reverse proxy is not working due to the dyn dns.

Can this be done with dynamic dns???

Many thanks,

Kevin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it certainly can be done.  But it will require a few things and your description is a bit vague so I'll give you a fairly generic answer:

For it to work, every DNS entry for your zone must be changed to point to your external (dynamically changing) IP address.  So when your router gets a new external address, you'll need to have dynamic DNS change the content of your zone to reflect this.  You haven't said how you're doing this, but it sounds like you have it working.  But if you're just running bind on your internal LAN and only changing it there, it won't work.  If you own, for example, "mylan.com" then you need to tell ".com" that your name server has changed addresses too and that the authority has moved.  It is unlikely you can do that change in an automated fashion.  Instead, you'll likely need an external DNS provider for "mylan.com" that you can update without changing the registered NS records for mylan.com itself.

But to make it worse, if you have your internal LAN behind a NATing router (which is why you have 192.168....) then you need to tell the NAT box to do forwarding as well.  Your NAT box will need to forward everything coming in to its address on port 53 (UDP and TCP both) to your internal box for DNS, and everything to port 80 to your internal box.  And possibly 8082 and 8083 as well, but if you have the proxying set up properly this shouldn't be necessary.